# OnePlusOne layout-large or layout-normal?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, screen-size

In order to support multiple screens for an Android app on Eclipse, I have different folders like "layout-small", "layout-normal"...

My question is why is the OnePlus One, with 5.5", using "layout-normal" instead of "layout-large"?

Is there a way to change that behaviour?

Comment: oneplusone is xxhdpi, keep your drawables resources in that folder

Comment: Go to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OnePlus` One is not large screen size. It's Normal Screen size with `XXDPI` and resolution in `dp` is `640x360dp`

So, your resouce folder must be `layout-normal` not `layout-large`